# How to avoid Logged User change after refreshing page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie Method in my application.after Client login i am setting  **FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserNo.Text.Trim(), false);**

and in web.config file i set

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="PasswordEntry.aspx" path="/" timeout="1"></forms>
    </authentication>
```

after 1 minute (Page refreshing) i am getting Administrator data.its not right.Please tell me where the problem is ? and the solution also.

Thanks in advance.
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable [`slidingExpiration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) which is enabled by default and which renews your authentication ticket for yet another minute at every request:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms 
        loginUrl="PasswordEntry.aspx" 
        path="/" 
        timeout="1" 
        slidingExpiration="false" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: I love how every time i refresh the question, your answer gets better formatted and more informing, waiting for it to get accepted to +1.